# Add csrf token and parameterName into logout link

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security

I have link in the menu:

```
<li><a href="<spring:url value="/logout" />">Logout</a></li>
```

It worked perfectly before I did setup for csrf protection in spring-security xml settings:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <csrf />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/success" />
</http>
```

Now, I have problem because logout doesn't have csrf and it doesn't works. Just return page with not found code 404. How to add those parameters into my logout link:

```
"${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With CSRF enabled you can only logout using a *POST* request. To do so you will need to create a form (or use a AJAX request) to submit your CSRF token.

```
<form action="/logout" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
</form>
```

Or you could send a AJAX request.

```
function changeHandler() {
    // request is done and issues a redirect
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 302) {
        location.refresh();
    }
}

var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open('POST', '/logout', true);
r.onreadystatechange = changeHandler;
r.setRequestHeader('${_csrf.headerName}', '${_csrf.token}');
r.send();
```

Comment: Can you please help me with ajax request? I prefer ajax way.